# How to crop coverage which is the result of gs:BarnesSurface with WPS chain in sld? It's throw a Error

Tags: geoserver, sld, wps

I would like to perform a gs:CropCoverage of the Raster Layer which is the result of gs:BarnesSurface

[image]

The SLD file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
     xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
     xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>CropCoverage</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Title>Crop Coverage</Title>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Transformation>
                    <ogc:Function name="gs:CropCoverage">
                        <!-- crop coverage -->
                        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                            <ogc:Literal>coverage</ogc:Literal>

                            <ogc:Function name="gs:BarnesSurface">

                                <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                                    <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Function>

                                <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                                    <ogc:Literal>valueAttr</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>o3_8h</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Function>

                                <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                                    <ogc:Literal>scale</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>300000</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Function>

                                <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                                    <ogc:Literal>convergence</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>0.2</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Function>

                                <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                                    <ogc:Literal>passes</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Function>

                                <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                                    <ogc:Literal>minObservations</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Function>

                                <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                                    <ogc:Literal>maxObservationDistance</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>300000</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Function>

                                <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                                    <ogc:Literal>pixelsPerCell</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Function>

                                <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                                    <ogc:Literal>queryBuffer</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>1100000</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Function>

                                <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                                    <ogc:Literal>outputBBOX</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Function name="env">
                                        <ogc:Literal>wms_bbox</ogc:Literal>
                                    </ogc:Function>
                                </ogc:Function>

                                <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                                    <ogc:Literal>outputWidth</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Function name="env">
                                        <ogc:Literal>wms_width</ogc:Literal>
                                    </ogc:Function>
                                </ogc:Function>

                                <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                                    <ogc:Literal>outputHeight</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Function name="env">
                                        <ogc:Literal>wms_height</ogc:Literal>
                                    </ogc:Function>
                                </ogc:Function>

                            </ogc:Function>

                        </ogc:Function>
                        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                            <ogc:Literal>cropShape</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Function name="env">
                                <ogc:Literal>shape</ogc:Literal>
                                <ogc:Literal>
                                    POLYGON((12679220.5449551 4733685.69206447,12898591.968062 4713152.82010571,13058134.8212306 4439899.46114607,13030214.821926 4052340.79528089,12735060.5435642 4028261.06778929,12483780.5498236 4076471.69742768,12180649.1288033 4330580.49744829,12264409.1267168 4525151.37667656,12264409.1267168 4525151.37667656,12364123.4099472 4728548.57087371,12364123.4099472 4728548.57087371,12679220.5449551 4733685.69206447))
                                  </ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:Function>
                        </ogc:Function>
                    </ogc:Function>
                </Transformation>
                <Rule>
                    <Name>rule1</Name>
                    <RasterSymbolizer></RasterSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

The Error Info is below:

Error rendering coverage on the fast path
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to evaluate the process function, error is: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
Failed to evaluate the process function, error is: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
java.io.IOExceptionorg.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
  建议："POLYGON ((-�" <-- parse error at position 12 within geometry
ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
  建议："POLYGON ((-�" <-- parse error at position 12 within geometry

Where Error??????

But It's OK When I Use below sld to crop a raster:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
     xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
     xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>CropCoverage</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Crop Coverage</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Transformation>
          <ogc:Function name="gs:CropCoverage">
            <!-- crop coverage -->
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>coverage</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>cropShape</ogc:Literal>

                <ogc:Literal>POLYGON((12679220.5449551 4733685.69206447,12898591.968062 4713152.82010571,13058134.8212306 4439899.46114607,13030214.821926 4052340.79528089,12735060.5435642 4028261.06778929,12483780.5498236 4076471.69742768,12180649.1288033 4330580.49744829,12264409.1267168 4525151.37667656,12264409.1267168 4525151.37667656,12364123.4099472 4728548.57087371,12364123.4099472 4728548.57087371,12679220.5449551 4733685.69206447))</ogc:Literal>

            </ogc:Function>
          </ogc:Function>
        </Transformation>
        <Rule>
          <Name>rule1</Name>
          <RasterSymbolizer>


        </RasterSymbolizer>
      </Rule>
    </FeatureTypeStyle>
  </UserStyle>
</NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post but there is no clear solution.. I noticed something odd in the `SLD`. The `<ogc:Function name="parameter">` of the `<ogc:Function name="gs:CropCoverage">` should be close before the `<ogc:Function name="gs:BarnesSurface">` starts, no? Anyway, this did get rid of the above error in my case.

I was not yet successful in combining `gs:CropCoverage` and `gs:BarnesSurface`, but that is related to an issue with `gs:CropCoverage` it seems (it was in my case using GeoServer 2.8.3)

Answer (score 0):

try disabling the geometry simplification flag in your PostGIS store configuration in GeoServer.

Comment: Could you give more information as to why this might be? And are you sure he has that flag set. I have seen that error before, but never from simplification, though that can lead to other geometry errors.

Comment: Hi  Andrea Aime. I have disabling the geometry simplification flag in PostGIS store configuration in GeoServer. But there is still the same error!